# Highest value(max) from mongodb collection error - Flask Python

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, flask-pymongo

I am trying to get the highest value for `nr` from a mongo database collection named `prob` that looks like this for now:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ae9d062f36d282906c59736"
    },
    "nr": 1,
    "nume": "numeunu",
    "enunt": "-",
    "datedeintrare": "-",
    "datedeiesire": "-"
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ae9f190f36d282906c5b461"
    },
    "nr": 2,
    "nume": "numedoi",
    "enunt": "-",
    "datedeintrare": "-",
    "datedeiesire": "-"
}
```

My testing flask code is:

```
@app.route('/test')
def testaree():
    prob = mongo.db.prob
    return prob.find().sort({"nr":-1}).limit(1)
```

but it gives me an error `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for sorting using pymongo is different from the mongo query language.
In the above code the expression used is

```
sort({"nr":-1})
```

However , that is a mongo shell query syntax. When using pymongo it should be

```
sort("nr", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

You could also use find_one instead of a limit clause once the data is sorted.

```
db.prob.find_one(sort=[("nr", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

Comment: Thank you! But now how do I actually assign to a variable the first value that it founds (since it sorts in descending)(sorry if I am noob )

Comment: You could return the value without assigning to variable     `db.prob.find_one(sort=[("nr",pymongo.DESCENDING)])['nr']`